# Coefficient of two power series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

How do I find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}x^j$?

Comment: It is $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac  {(-1)^k} {k!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What are the thoughts behind the answer please?

Comment: Try the finite case first. See if you can compare coefficients for $(\sum_0^n a_ix^i)(\sum_0^n b_jx^j)=\sum_0^{2n}c_kx^k$

Comment: You try to accumulate all the powers of $x^n$ in that product. Or in other words you need to partition $n$ into at most two parts.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being lazy, I started with a small problem
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{7}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\sum_{j = 0}^{76}x^j=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{3 x^4}{8}+\frac{11 x^5}{30}+\frac{53
   x^6}{144}+\frac{103 x^7}{280}+\cdots=\sum_{k = 0}^{7}\frac{a_n}{b_n}x^n$$

Coefficients $a_n$ correspond to sequence $A053557$ in $OEIS$ (have a look [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C11%2C53%2C103&sort=&language=&go=Search)) and coefficients $b_n$ correspond to sequence $A053556$ in $OEIS$ (have a look [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C8%2C30%2C144%2C280&sort=&language=&go=Search)) making
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{(!n)}{n!}$$ where appears the subfactorial function (also called the derangement number) (have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html))

Answer (score 0):

Consider the finite case.

$$\sum_0^n a_ix^i\sum_0^n b_jx^j=a_0b_0+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)x+(a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2+\ldots=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\sum_{j=0}^ka_jb_{k-j}x^k$$

Can you extend it for the infinite case now?